# normal reverse for loop to reverse jquery .each

Tags: jquery, for-loop, each

Want to perform a `for` loop but it has to be a reverse loop like the following:

```
for (var i = arguments.length; i > 0; i -= 2)
```

i am doing it like this without being able to achieve the desired result:

```
 $.each(arguments.reverse(), function(i, result)
```

I understand that with `reverse` i will loop from the end to the begining of the array.

But how can i do that two at a time and stop when `i = 0`?

Comment: why not a `for loop`?

Comment: Like @Grundy said, if you have a working JavaScript, why would you convert it in jQuery?

Comment: Because i want to learn jquery. why is that weird i dont get it.

Comment: @João for learning purpose, i guess it is ok, for practical use, it would be *illogical*.

Comment: The problem is how can i get result from the normal for loop? like i do with the each jquery loop

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it:

```
$.each(arguments.reverse(), function(i, result){
    if(i%2 == 0){
       // Do your task here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `.each()` to process indices: `0, 2, 4`:

```
$.each($.grep(arguments.reverse(),function(v,i)  { return i%2 === 0; }), function(i, result)
```